# Fade in after function is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery function which is re-aligning my site navigation.

Once this navigation has been altered (the margin added), I would like to fade the navigation in.

```
function logoPosition() {

    var totalLeft = 0,
        totalRight = 0;

    $('li.left').each(function() {
        totalLeft += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
    });

    $('li.right').each(function() {
        totalRight += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
    });

    var diff = Math.abs(totalRight - totalLeft),
        rePosition = '-'+diff+'px';

    $nav.css({ 'margin-left' : rePosition });

}
logoPosition();
```

I have tried:

```
$.when( logoPosition() ).then( **load nav back in** );
```

But this just loads the nav back in instantly before the margin has been added.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be great if we have a FIDDLE here

Comment: Did you try a callback?

Comment: There is no async operation in your code, so just fade in element... If there is some kind of animation/transition e.g in CSS, then add relevant info in question

Comment: is the `$nav` representing the navigation you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML / CSS set the navigations styling to:

```
opacity: 0;
```

Then when your function is completed add:

```
$(".nav").fadeTo(500, 1);
```

(The above assumed your nav bar has the class of .nav attached)